# Way to display a Django ForeignKey's field in admin form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have a model 'A' with a foreign key 'b', and in the admin I want to have the standard pulldown with the names from b.  But I also want to display a secondary field for b, preferably in the help_text, or something like that, but I'll take it as part of the name as long as I can do some formatting on it, and that it doesn't override the name for other models that have the same foreign key.

Any pointers?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want? Your explanation is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a custom widget that inherits from the default one and adds this piece of information to the rendering